# Peter Kämpf, our first user to break 100,000

Tags: discussion

I figured it'd happen at some point, congratulations Peter!  I've personally benefited from several of your answers, and I've heard the same sentiment from many other users on Aviation Stack Exchange.  Thanks for all you've done!

It's been a lot of fun being here for the last couple years, watching that number spiral slowly upwards.  Big milestone for Peter and the site in general :).

[https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/1961/peter-kämpf](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/1961/peter-k%C3%A4mpf)

---

*I know, it's not a question.  But it's nifty, and I just wanted to make sure people are aware.*

Comment: Posts on meta don't have to be questions.

Comment: Now Peter should write an answer so that he can [get a Guru badge for a question about himself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/271431).

Comment: I've just looked at his rep history. Since 5/19/2016, he has a positive rep change *every single day* up to today. That is *239 consecutive days*.

Comment: Peter has the right stuff...

Comment: @kevin He's also currently only 2 days short of getting the Legendary badge for earning at least 200 rep on 150 different days. 1,035 answers. And 7 questions.

Comment: that means that on average, every answer has been upvoted 10+ times!

Comment: Can we say thank you Peter, here as a comment? Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 27):

*In recognition of your many contributions to Aviation.StackExchange, as evidenced by your 100,000 site rep, the Av.SE community is proud to present...*

## The most interesting aviator in the world, Peter Kämpf

---

1. Peter Kämpf once had lunch with Amelia Earhart.  In 1941.
2. Eyepatches are issued to the flight crew of any aircraft that Peter Kämpf is aboard. If they accidentally look directly at Peter Kämpf, they can complete the flight using their other eye.
3. Peter Kämpf can pour iced tea while performing [Pugachev's Cobra](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/24304/167).
4. [...in an F-16](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/16426/167)
5. Peter Kämpf invented the CAT IV approach. To date, the only person certified to fly one is Peter Kämpf.
6. Peter Kämpf can fly a GPS approach with nothing but a wristwatch. He memorizes the ephemeris and almanac and calculates PRN on the fly.
7. Maverick communicates with Russian pilots using sign language. Peter Kämpf communicates with Russian pilots using Braille.
8. Peter Kämpf once executed a go-around while landing the Space Shuttle.
9. When Peter Kämpf gets spatial disorientation, it's because space is mistaken.
10. The NTSB has revised their list of hazardous attitudes. It now reads: Peter Kämpf, Peter Kämpf, impulsivity, resignation, and anti-Peter Kämpf.
11. If you meow on guard a miniature version of Peter Kämpf will appear in your artificial horizon and offer to teach you the secrets of the CAT IV approach.
12. In a past life Peter Kämpf was the now-unknown third [Horton Brother](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horten_brothers?wprov=sfsi1)
13. Peter Kämpf was able to write in MathJax before he said his first word and designed his first wing at age 3.
14. There is an easter egg in B777 CDU, if you enter PTRKP waypoint, an ASCII image of Peter's face is displayed.
15. Peter has inherited the Spruce Goose blueprints in a secret testament discovered in 2015, and has been instructed by Howard Hughes to make it fly.
16. There is an entire wing of Area 51 dedicated to the life and times of Peter Kämpf.
17. He doesn't always drink, but when he does, he prefers JP-7.
18. Peter Kämpf can reliably make the [impossible turn](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/786/167) from any altitude.
19. To simplify explanations of ground effect, Peter Kämpf invented an invisible cushion made out of air. He takes it with him when he goes camping.
20. The FAA has an official [Letter of Correction](https://www.aopa.org/training-and-safety/pic-archive/faa-enforcement/faa-enforcement) in their file on Peter Kämpf.  If there are no other incidents for the next 24 months, he will consider removing it.
21. Peter Kämpf does not actually fly, he just climbs into an aircraft and the earth stays out of his way.
22. Peter Kämpf has a record for gliding for 21 hours over the alps...in a box.
23. Peter Kämpf knows the [name of the wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Name_of_the_Wind).
24. The world is made of two kinds of people: The ones who can understand Peter Kämpf explanations, and the others.
25. Flight crews are instructed to remove the winglets and [reattach them properly](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/is-a-winglet-better-than-an-equal-span-extension) if Peter Kämpf is on board.
26. Peter Kämpf is the only pilot to [climb by reducing lift](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12714/why-do-airplanes-lift-up-their-nose-to-climb/12720#12720).
27. The "100 Grand Bar" has been renamed.  It is henceforth known as a "Peter Kämpf Food Unit."
28. Peter Kämpf is *the* person [Lilium](http://lilium-aviation.com/) has [contacted for advice](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/35437/18733) when building an aircraft.
29. Peter Kämpf [reveals wasted eu funds](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18887/cruiser-feeder-concept-feasible?noredirect=1&lq=1).
30. There's an Easter egg to be won if you can persuade Peter Kämpf to talk about how to [tailor roll stick forces](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/37814/14897).

Comment: This list is community wiki - please add to it!

Comment: For those who hadn't heard of it: [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/188498), the post that probably inspired this one.

Comment: ... every morning, Peter Kämpf does fifty pushups with both hands, fifty pushups with each hand, and fifty pushups with no hands?

Comment: @E.P. lol, you can edit the post and add that in if you want, it's community wiki :)

Comment: @JayCarr naw, that's an old Chuck Norris one, the current list is too pristinely aviationy to soil it with something as mundane as exercise. Though on the other hand the no-hands pushup isn't as unrelated to aviation in the end?

Comment: Exercise?  That's like a pilot's kryptonite!

Comment: `make the impossible turn from any altitude` is not a problem. Given enough airspeed, you can do it at any altitude.

Comment: The "100 Grand Bar" is being renamed.  It is henceforth known as a "Peter Kämpf Food Unit."

Comment: @acpilot You should add that to the list as well :)

Comment: @kevin yes, but Peter can do it with negative airspeed (go ahead, try and wrap your head around that.)